# Where is QWebView?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qwebview

I am trying to insert a QWebView into my QMainWindow in Qt Creator. However, I can't find it:

It is supposed to be in there in this group, but it's not.

[image]

I am using Qt Creator 2.01 on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

Comment: This is strange. I have the same version, and QWebView is just under QDeclarativeView. Maybe you should try reinstall Qt Creator ?

Comment: @Jérôme: I did. I installed 2.1 but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that you haven't installed all Qt dev packages (specifically QtWebkit-dev, if such a beast exists in Ubuntu; it might because the library is quite large). Otherwise it might be a packaging error and should be reported to Ubuntu people.

Comment: +1 It's a bug alright. I filed it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/674367